# Can I connect an old AWS IoT button to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

I've recently got hold of what I presume is a "first edition" Amazon IoT button that was handed out at a re:Invent event a few years ago, and I'm having difficulty setting it up on today's AWS. It looks like this: http://tinypic.com/r/2hgckz4/9.

I have tried:

- The ConfigureMe Wi-Fi route: I can select the wireless network *but I cannot upload the certificate*. There is simply not a box to do it. The ConfigureMe screen looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gYnL.jpg. When I press Configure, the button connects to Wi-Fi (I think) but then displays red flashes I guess because it can't securely connect to AWS.
- The AWS IoT iOS app, which doesn't make any progress beyond the spinner when after connecting to the Wi-Fi network.
- The Amazon Shopping app setup for Dash Buttons, which successfully connects via Bluetooth and emits some ultrasound pips, but then fails for an unspecified reason.

Is my button too old? It seems to be missing the certificate upload box and the screen doesn't match the documentation. Is there any way I can get this button to connect to AWS IoT now?

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload certificates on this generation of the IoT button.

This button embeds all of its configuration internally, and is sending a message to a predefined AWS IoT endpoint. There is a special web page on the cloud to configure this particular button, I would suggest requesting the details back to the person which handed the button to you.

**EDIT:**

You can find details on how to associate your 1st generation button to your AWS account by following [this article](https://www.hackster.io/shivanshsingh/aws-cloud-enabled-burglar-alarm-ba1af1) which also provides a [video of the procedure](https://s3.amazonaws.com/iotbutton-getting-started/iot-button-getting-started.mp4).

Comment: Thanks. I do have the "activation code" supplied with the button which is used for claiming the certificate – is the form to do that still online anywhere? I can't find anything about that in documentation.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide the pointers to the resources associated with your question.